# Django logger not logging log levels below Warning

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-logging

I am trying to configure logger in the Django Framework. I have changed the logging level to DEBUG in both handler and logger and still the INFO log is not getting logged. It only shows log upto Warning and not further from there.

```
# app/views/test.py
# def test()
        print("#"*10, logger.level,logger.name) #Log level is 10 when printed
        logger.info("This is an informational message.")
        logger.debug("This is a debug message.")
        logger.warning("This is a warning message.")
        logger.error("This is an error message.")
        logger.critical("This is a critical message.")
```

## Setting.py file log dict

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'level':'DEBUG'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'app': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

Output:

```
WARNING 2023-12-05 07:06:46,934 test This is a warning message.
ERROR 2023-12-05 07:06:46,935 test This is an error message.
CRITICAL 2023-12-05 07:06:46,935 test This is a critical message.
```

The INFO and DEBUG log level message is not logged.